# Modifying generic maps in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, collections

I'm new to the Scala landscape after spending the last 10 years in Java and the last ~year in Groovy. Hi Scala!

For the life of me I can't seem to get the following code snippet to compile, and its *just* complicated enough to the point where the Google Gods aren't helping me.

I have a map that will contain Strings for keys and Lists of Tuples for values. The tuples will be a String-Long pair. In Groovy this would look like:

```
Map<String,List<Tuple2<String,Long>>> data = [:]
```

I need to be able to add and modify keys and values for this map. Specifically, I need to:

1. Add to the List of Tuples for existing keys
2. If a key doesn't exist, instantiate a new List of Tuples, and then add the key and list as a map entry

In Groovy this would look like:

```
Map<String,List<String,Long>> data = [:]

def addData(String key, String message) {
    Long currTime = System.currentTimestampInMillis()
    Tuple2<String,Long> tuple = new Tuple2<String,Long>(message, tuple)

    if(data.contains(key)) {
        data.key << tuple
    } else {
        data[key] = new List<Tuple2<String,Long>>()
        data.key << tuple
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do this in Scala, albeit unsuccessfully.

My best attempt thus far:

```
object MapUtils {
    // var data : Map[String,ListBuffer[(String,Long)]] = Map()
    val data = collection.mutable.Map[String, ListBuffer[(String, Long)]]()

    def addData(key : String, message : String) : Unit = {
        val newTuple = (message, System.currentTimeMillis())
        val optionalOldValue = data.get(key)

        optionalOldValue match {
            case Some(olderBufferList) => olderBufferList += newTuple
            case None => data
                .put(key, ListBuffer[(String, Long)](newTuple))
        }
    }
}
```

Complains with this compiler error on the `case Some(olderBufferList) => olderBufferList += newTuple` line:

```
value += is not a member of Any
```

Any ideas what I can do to get this compiling & working?

Comment: `ListBuffer[String,Long]` -> `ListBuffer[(String,Long)]`

Comment: Thanks @talex (+1) - please see my changes which incorporate your suggestion. This produces a new compiler error. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Which string produce it?

Comment: you declare a `var tupleOpt : ListBuffer[String,Long] -> ListBuffer[(String,Long)]` but don't assign any value to it.

Comment: and I don't think `ListBuffer[String,Long]` takes two type paramereters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `import` for `ListBuffer`. The following code works perfectly fine in 2.9.1 (tested on [TryScala](http://TryScala.com/)), 2.11.7 (tested on [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/B1Iji8)) and 2.11.8. Note the only addition is the first line adding the `import`:

```
import collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object MapUtils {
    // var data : Map[String,ListBuffer[(String,Long)]] = Map()
    val data = collection.mutable.Map[String, ListBuffer[(String, Long)]]()

    def addData(key : String, message : String) : Unit = {
        val newTuple = (message, System.currentTimeMillis())
        val optionalOldValue = data.get(key)

        optionalOldValue match {
            case Some(olderBufferList) => olderBufferList += newTuple
            case None => data
                .put(key, ListBuffer[(String, Long)](newTuple))
        }
    }
}

MapUtils.addData("123", "message 1")
MapUtils.addData("456", "message 2")

MapUtils.data
//=> Map(456 -> ListBuffer((message 2,1472925061065)), 123 -> ListBuffer((message 1,1472925060926)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The short version for your needs will be:

```
val map = mutable.Map[String, ListBuffer[(String, Long)]]()
map.put(key, map.getOrElse(key, ListBuffer[(String, Long)]()) += ((message, System.currentTimeMillis())))
```

You have some syntax issues with your code, If I'll try to change addData it would look like this:

```
def addData(key : String, message : String) : Unit = {
  val newTuple = (message, System.currentTimeMillis())
  val optionalOldValue = map.get(key)

  optionalOldValue match {
    case Some(olderBufferList) => olderBufferList += newTuple
    case None => map.put(key, ListBuffer[(String, Long)](newTuple))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael K. (+1) - I think we're close but Scala doesn't seem to like the line with your `case Non =>...` statement. It doesn't like the use of `map.put` there, saying `value put is not a member of Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(String, Long)]]`. Any ideas?

Comment: The default map implementation in Scala is immutable. In order to use mutable map we should explicitly ask to use the mutable collection. val map = mutable.Map[String, ListBuffer[(String, Long)]]()

Comment: Thanks again @Michel K (+1) - please see my edit above. I have now included the full SSCCE including the class definition and `data` instantiation. When I comment out my `data` instantiation and replace it with  your suggestion above, the Scala compiler now complains `not found: value mutable`.

Comment: `collection.mutable.Map[...]()`

Comment: Thanks @jwvh (+1) - please see my edits. Now I'm getting `value += is not a member of Any` in the `case Some(...` line.

Comment: `import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer`

Comment: Thanks @jwvh please see [my gist of this](https://gist.github.com/zharvey-welltok/763ca2e11eb40c373b5f6d560decac4b), as you can see, the `import` statement *is* there. But this code does not compile.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you.  I plugged it in to my IDE (Intellij 2016.2.2). It compiles and runs for me.